# How can I delete a detail row in master-detail grid with Ag Grid?

Tags: api, vuejs2, ag-grid, delete-row, ag-grid-vue

I am using [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/master-detail/) Ag Grid functionality. The only place I was able to find where the detail rows get passed to the Ag Grid is here:

```
    getDetailRowData: params => {
        params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
    }
```

So, once the `callRecords` get passed, there is no way to modify the detail rows. I tried keeping track of the `callRecords` and then modifying the corresponding array, but it did not have any effect:

```
getDetailRowData: params => {
    this.callRecords = params.data.callRecords;
    params.successCallback(this.callRecords);
}

//later on I do
this.callRecords.splice(0, 1);
```

So, is there any way to modify (remove in my particular case) the detail rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke a transaction update on the master row (as described [in the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/data-update-transactions/)):

```
this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ update: [masterDataToUpdate] });
```

Provided that you set `refreshStrategy: 'rows'` in Detail Cell Renderer, the `getDetailRowData` callback will be invoked again and detail grid refreshed. This is described [in the docs here](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/master-detail-refresh/).